# Pandas iteration over rows for features calculation

Tags: python, performance, pandas, iteration

I have a pandas data frame and I want to calculate some features based on some `short_window`, `long_window` and `bins` values. More specifically, for each different row, I want to calculate some features. In order to do so, I move one row forward the `df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row]` such as in the first iteration the pandas data frame for `row=0` would be `df_long = df.loc[0:50+0]` and some features would be calculated based on this data frame, for `row=1` would be `df_long = df.loc[1:50+1]` and some other features would be calculated and continues.

```py
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

bins = 12
short_window = 10
long_window = 50

# seed random number generator
seed(1)

price = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', freq='30min'),
    'value': randint(2, 20, 1489),
    'amount': randint(50, 200, 1489)
})


def vap(row, df, short_window, long_window, bins):

    df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row]
    df_short = df_long.tail(short_window)

    binning = pd.cut(df_long['value'], bins, retbins=True)[1]
    group_months = pd.DataFrame(df_short['amount'].groupby(pd.cut(df_short['value'], binning)).sum())

    return group_months['amount'].tolist(),  df.loc[long_window + row + 1, 'DATE_TIME']


def feature_extraction(data, short_window, long_window, bins):

    # Vap feature extraction
    ls = [f"feature{row + 1}" for row in range(bins)]
    amount, date = zip(*Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(vap)(i, data, short_window, long_window, bins)
                                                for i in range(0, data.shape[0] - long_window - 1)))
    temp = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['DATE_TIME'])
    temp[ls] = pd.DataFrame(amount, index=temp.index)
    data = data.merge(temp, on='DATE_TIME', how='outer')

    return data


df = feature_extraction(price, short_window, long_window, bins)
```

I tried to run it in parallel in order to save time but due to the dimensions of my data, it takes a long of time to finish.

Is there any way to change this iterative process `(df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row])` in order to reduce the computational cost? I was wondering if there is any way to use pandas.rolling but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: This might be of use: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html. Is this program runnable? Can you explain what it's meant to do?

Comment: Yes, it is runnable. For each different pandas data frame of a specific length calculates some features. Then this is being done for each different row. I know pandas rolling but I don't know how there is a way to run this example with pandas.rolling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just some stylistic suggestions

## Constants

Constants in your program should be UPPERCASE. ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants))

```
bins -> BINS
short_window -> SHORT_WINDOW
long_window -> LONG_WINDOW
price -> PRICE
```

## Docstrings

You can add docstrings to your functions to allow more description about the function and
about the parameters it accepts and the value(s) it returns, if any. ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings))

```
def vap(row, df, short_window, long_window, bins):
    """
    Description Here

    :param row: Description Here
    :param df: Description Here
    :param short_window: Description Here
    :param long_window: Description Here
    :param bins: Description Here

    :return: Description Here
    """
```

## Type Hints

You can add type hints to your functions to show what types of parameters are accepted, and what
types are returned.

You can also use `typing`'s `NewVar` to create custom types to return.

```
from typing import List

PandasTimeStamp = NewType("PandasTimeStamp", pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)

def vap(row: int, df: pd.DataFrame, short_window: int, long_window: int, bins: int) -> List, PandasTimeStamp:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but this suggestion doesn't solve my problem.